# Using an external variable to manipulate the result in PHP pulled from an XML file

Tags: php, xml

I am simply looking to use an external variable gained from a HTML file through the GET function to choose which object to output to the user. After some attempts and researching sites for using variables like this I have no idea apart from using a constant.

```html
$xml=simplexml_load_file("XMLtest.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$passID = $_GET["IDsend"];
echo "ID Recieved: " . $passID;
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->year . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->month . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->day . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->projection . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->recommendedStaff . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->staffWages . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->actual . "<br>";
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<january>
 <finances id="1">
  <year>2016</year>
  <month>01</month>
  <day>01</day>
  <projection>414</projection>
  <recommendedStaff>20</recommendedStaff>
  <staffWages>100</staffWages>
  <actual>250</actual>
 </finances>
 <finances id="2">
  <year>2016</year>
  <month>01</month>
  <day>02</day>
  <projection>124</projection>
  <recommendedStaff>8</recommendedStaff>
  <staffWages>150</staffWages>
  <actual>250</actual>
 </finances>
 <finances id="3">
  <year>2016</year>
  <month>01</month>
  <day>03</day>
  <projection>687</projection>
  <recommendedStaff>20</recommendedStaff>
  <staffWages>150</staffWages>
  <actual>250</actual>
 </finances>
</january>
```

Comment: `$_GET` is an array passed via a URL parameter. As long as the page you are calling has the URL parameter, e.g. `/yourpage.php?IDsend=somevariable`, `$passID` will be assigned that value

Comment: @justbaron That is what I believed from my research although when I do use it, it assigns passID as the value however doesn't use it within the square brackets and returns an empty string.

Comment: What are the URL parameters you are using?

Comment: @justbaron I am just using integers and sending them as numbers in HTML file to the PHP file as I did think that was the issue.

Comment: What are the URL parameters you are using to access the PHP file?

Comment: As I understand it, you are having trouble getting the value of `$passID = $_GET['IDsend'];`, correct? If so, then the URL you use to access the page, must have a parameter, e.g. `yourpage.php?IDsend=$some_value`.

Comment: @justbaron If this is what you are looking for it is __Test3.php?IDsend=1__

Comment: It works giving the value I can echo that perfectly fine, however when used within the echo $xml as the index value it returns empty values.

Comment: OK, have you tried printing the value of `$_GET['IDsend']` on this page?

Comment: Ah, OK. So it might be helpful to post some code of your XMLtest.xml.

Comment: @justbaron I have edited the post above to include it, I'm puzzled as this is my first time using PHP and XML together. It works will any constant but the variable that is assigned correctly seems to be null when entered into the index value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, convert the `$_GET['IDsend']` variable to an integer, using `intval()`:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("XMLtest.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$passID = intval($_GET["IDsend"]);
echo "ID Recieved: " . $passID;
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->year . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->month . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->day . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->projection . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->recommendedStaff . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->staffWages . ", ";
echo $xml->finances[$passID]->actual . "<br>";
```

This returns: `ID Recieved: 12016, 01, 02, 124, 8, 150, 250`

Comment: I had no idea intval was a thing, is there any other ways of converting variables in PHP?

Comment: strval(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php, type juggling: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php